# Positioning .cls files in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: packages, installing, ubuntu

I have a research paper accepted to a journal and the editor asked me to use certain file  with `.cls` and I am confused about where exactly I need to dump this file `.cls` ?

I tried to dump it to /usr/local/share/texmf/  but it is not giving me the right pdf file. Can you help please ?

Comment: If it is just for a one-off use, put it in the same folder as the .tex file you are writing...

Comment: See [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://goo.gl/ByVnz)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.